# Set values in a knative service.yaml file using environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, knative

Is there a way to set the values of some keys in a Knative `service.yaml` file using environment variables?

---

**More detail**

I am trying to deploy a Knative service to a Kubernetes cluster using GitLab CI. Some of the variables in my `service.yaml` file depend on the project and environment of the GitLab CI pipeline. Is there a way I can seamlessly plug those values into my `service.yaml` file without resorting to hacks like `sed -i ...`?

For example, given the following script, I want the `$(KUBE_NAMESPACE)`, `$(CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG)`, and `$(CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG)` values to be replaced by accordingly-named environment variables.

```yaml
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: design
  namespace: "$(KUBE_NAMESPACE)"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: design-v1
      annotations:
        app.gitlab.com/env: "$(CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG)"
        app.gitlab.com/app: "$(CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG)"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-container
          image: ...
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      containerConcurrency: 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a great way to expand environment variables inside of an existing yaml, but if you don't want to use sed, you might be able to use [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html):

```
envsubst < original.yaml > modified.yaml
```

You would just run this command before you use the yaml to expand the environment variables contained within it.

Also I think you'll need your variables to use curly braces, instead of parentheses, like this: `${KUBE_NAMESPACE}`.

EDIT: You might also be able to use this inline like this: `kubectl apply -f <(envsubst < service.yaml)`

Answer (score 2):

More than a Knative issue this is more of Kubernetes limitation. Kubernetes allows some expansion but not in annotations or namespace definitions. For example, you can do it in container env definitions:

```yaml
containers:
- env:
  - name: PODID
    valueFrom: ...
  - name: LOG_PATH
    value: /var/log/$(PODID)
```

If this is a CI/CD system like Gitlab the environment variables should be in a shell environment, so a simple shell expansion will do. For example.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: design
  namespace: "${KUBE_NAMESPACE}"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: design-v1
      annotations:
        app.gitlab.com/env: "${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}"
        app.gitlab.com/app: "${CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG}"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: user-container
          image: ...
      timeoutSeconds: 600
      containerConcurrency: 8
" | kubectl apply -f -
```

You can also use [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) as a helper like mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the containers env section! I saw the `env` section in the docs and this is what made me think it may be possible to extract environment variables from the calling process.